# SCSS sprite positions calculatin generates invalid CSS

Tags: css, sass

I try to calculate a sprite position with the following scss

```
@mixin sprite-image($position, $row)
{
  background: url("/dist/image/sprite3.png") -$position * (1024 / 14)px $row * -(271/3)px;
}
```

When the css is generated I get the following invalid css for a position:

```
background: url("/dist/image/sprite3.png")-585.14286 px -90.33333 px; }
```

How should I generate valid css?

I also tried:

```
@mixin sprite-image($position, $row)
{
  background: url("/dist/image/sprite3.png") round(-$position * (1024 / 14))px  round($row * -(271/3))px;
}
```

Comment: Put brackets around the maths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin sprite-image($position, $row)
{
  background: url("/dist/image/sprite3.png") round(-$position * (1024 / 14)) *1px  round($row * -(271/3))*1px;
}
```

multiply it by 1px solved it, the problem was the space before px